# vector subscript out of range line 932 停止しない

Tags: c++, visual-studio

「vector subscript out of range line 932」のダイアログが出ているのですが、アプリケーションは動作しています。どういった場合にこうなるのでしょうか教えてください。
また、再発した時には「再試行」を選択してデバックにて呼び出しの履歴を見てみようと思うのですが、他に良い方法があれば教えてください。
環境はWin8Pro　VS2010 C++

Answer (score 1):

VC++のvectorのソースを見ると、`vector::operator[](size_type)`に範囲外の位置を指定すると出るようになっています。

---

> いえいえ、気が付いたらダイアログは出ているのですが(無視を含む）何も選択しない状態で、アプリケーションは動いているのです。

エラーが起きたスレッドとは別のスレッドが動いているのではないでしょうか？
以下のサンプルプログラムでは、サブスレッドは動き続けます。

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

unsigned int __stdcall sub_thread_func(void *)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        std::cerr << "sub thread i = " << i << std::endl;
        Sleep(1000);
    }

    _endthreadex(0);
    return 0;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HANDLE sub_thread_handle = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, &sub_thread_func, NULL, 0, NULL);
    if (!sub_thread_handle) {
        perror("sub thread");
        return 1;
    }
    while (true) {
        DWORD wait_result = WaitForSingleObject(sub_thread_handle, 1000);
        if (wait_result != WAIT_TIMEOUT) {
            break;  
        }
        std::vector<int> vec;
        int i = vec[0];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。範囲外にアクセスするとこのメッセージが出るのは理解しているのですが、その場合その状態で停止すると思っているのですが、アプリケーションは動いているので、どういった場合に停止しないのか知りたいのです。

Comment: 「アプリケーションは動いている」というのがよく分からないのですが、ダイアログで「無視」を選択したら先に進んだということでしょうか？

Comment: いえいえ、気が付いたらダイアログは出ているのですが(無視を含む）何も選択しない状態で、アプリケーションは動いているのです。

Comment: @eejyan2014  Visual C++ では警告メッセージを出してくれる様ですが、vector(正確には iterator 全般)に対する `[]` operator でのアクセスでは bounds check が行われません。範囲外アクセスの際にプログラムの実行を止めたい場合は、`[]` ではなく `at()` メソッドを使うと良いかと思います。[Are vectors more rigorous at checking out of bounds than heap arrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056597/are-vectors-more-rigorous-at-checking-out-of-bounds-than-heap-arrays) を参照してみて下さい。

Comment: @argusさん、回答ありがとうございます。そうだったのですか！at()を使ってみます。止まらないので不気味だったのです。ありがとうございました。

Comment: @eejyan2014 あぁ、状況が理解できました。エラーが起きたスレッドとは別のスレッドが動いているのではないでしょうか？

Comment: @alphaさん　回答ありがとうございます。記述していませんでしたが、確かに表のスレッドと裏のスレッドがあります。別のシステムからの指示で裏のスレッドから指示を出して表のスレッドで計算＆表示して裏にデータを渡して、裏は別システムに結果を返しています。ただ、表示が出た後も一連の動作をして表も裏も正常に動いています。不思議なんです。

Comment: @eejyan2014 指示毎にスレッドプールから空いているスレッドを割り当てて処理し終わったら返す、というようなこともしていないのでしょうか？

Comment: @alphaさん　ありがとうございます。裏スレッドはアプリ立ち上げ時に起動をかけているだけなんです。過去に何度も起きているのですが、たまたま自分が見つけた時「再試行」をやって止まったのですが、その時は呼び出し履歴の使い方をしらなかったので、追いかけることができませんでした。

Comment: 参考までに：Visual C++デバッグ実行時のassert等による警告ダイアログは、スレッド毎に表示されrます。複数スレッド上で同時にassert条件に違反すると、（最大でスレッド個数分の）警告ダイアログが一斉に表示されるケースもあります。

Comment: @yohjpさん　ありがとうございます。警告ダイアログは１つしか表示されません。